# apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS not showing aliases

Tags: apache

I'm running various version of apache 2.2.15 and 2.4(.6 and .7) on a number of servers (some ubuntu some centos) with similar configurations (2.4 and 2.2 differences are handled), but with different sites on each.

I have a script which uses apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS to get a list of the virtual hosts configured on a particular server, and it works fine to get me a list of virtual hosts, and my script happily handles the differences from output from 2.2 and 2.4

However, I need to include aliases in the output from my script.  Searching the internet tells me that the above should list aliases under each vhost.  It doesn't, on any of my servers.  https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51680 even says it was included in the main source at 2.4.1.  https://ma.ttias.be/apachectl-linux-get-entire-apache-vhost-configuration-one-output/ shows what looks like 2.2 output with aliases

Can anyone tell me how to make this work?

Thanks

EDIT:-

ezra-s asked for an example of what I'm seeing, this is typical, and comes from Ubuntu 14 running 2.4.7

```
/var/www/html$ apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   <host>.simon.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/simon.uk.conf:1)
*:8080                 <host>.simon.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/simon.uk.conf:42)
*:443                  ubuntu.<domain removed> (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ssl_proxy.conf:12)
```

As mentioned in comments I tracked the output down to `server/vhost.c:dump_a_vhost()` in the apache source.  In there is code that ultimately shows the above summary, over the detailed output with `aliases`, when there are no `NameVirtualHosts` defined.  Guess what, they were depreciated in 2.4 so can't be defined anymore.

I've logged this as a bug at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61019

Comment: If a moderator or someone thinks this question should be on serverfault rather than here, let me know and I'll sort it.

Comment: show what you have, but a simple apachectl -S should do the same with less wording and your aliases will show up.

Comment: I've kind of answered my own question now, as I went to the source to dig.  It turns out that in depreciating NameVirtualHosts the whole section of vhosts.c that dumps out the vhost including aliases, is disabled.  Only the first part of the function, dumping a summary will ever get called.  I've submitted a bug to that fact on https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61019